# Show that $f$ is univalent if in unit disk $|f'(z) - f'(0)|< |f'(0)|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $D = ${$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|\leq 1$}, $f$ analytic on $D$ such that
>   $|f'(z) - f'(0)|< |f'(0)|$ for all $z\in D$. Show that for any $a \neq b$, $f(a) \neq f(b)$.

I really need some hint or insight on how to start the proof.

In all my attempt, I could not find a way to make use of the inequality given, thus I know I'm on the wrong track.

Any help or insights is deeply appreciated.

Edit:

So turns out I have a solution, so do help to verify:

Suppose not, that is $a\neq b$ but $f(a) = f(b)$

consider $L$ to be the line segment from $a$ to $b$.

$|\int_L f'(z) - f'(0)dz| <|b-a||f'(0)|$ by M-L inequality and the conditions given.

This means $|f(b) - f(a) -(b-a)f'(0)|<|b-a||f'(0)|$
but since we assume $f(b) = f(a)$

$|b-a||f'(0)| <|b-a||f'(0)|$ contradiction.

Comment: OK. You are perfectly correct.