# $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ with $|f'(z) - f'(0)| < |f'(0)|$, then $f$ is one-to-one

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

> If $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ with $|f'(z) - f'(0)| < |f'(0)|$, then $f$ is one-to-one.

I am not really sure what I should be using in this question. I have tried to use integral representations and power series expansions. However, I am not sure how this will help to show $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Hint: take $z\neq w $ and write $|f(z)-f (w)|=|\int_{[z,w]} f'(\zeta)d\zeta|$. Now use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality on what?

Comment: $|\int_{[z,w]} f'(\zeta)d\zeta|\ge |\int_{[z,w]} f'(0)d\zeta|-|\int_{[z,w]} f'(\zeta)-f'(0)d\zeta|.$

Comment: Ah, I think I see now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265280/show-that-f-is-univalent-if-in-unit-disk-fz-f0-f0